# Breakdown a list of N elements to nodes of size S

Tags: algorithm, sorting, search, data-structures

Real life problem: I have an API that returns 5000 items at most. **At any given time, i can see how many items there are by filtering on price range. I can also find the most expensive item.** I need to breakdown these items to price ranges of size 5000 (node size) so i can collect them all.

Practical example below.

Populate a list.

```
price_list = []
for i in range(0, 100000):
    price_list.append(random.uniform(0, 100000))
```

Implement search function.

```
def get_prange_count(startp, endp):
    return len([r for r in price_list if r <= endp and r >= startp])
```

By using the get_prange_count function, break down all items in price_list to nodes of max 5000.

e.g.

```
[{"startp": 0, "endp": 3.5, "item_count": 5000}, 
{"startp": 3.51, "endp": 4.03, "item_count": 5000}]
```

I understand that this is an algorithm problem however i could not find the ideal one. I looked into binary search but i'm not looking for positions, i looked into hungarian algorithm but this doesn't seem to be an assignment problem.

Thanks in advance for any guidance,

EDIT:

```
5000 -> 2 for demonstration purposes. 

price_list = [0.1, 0.2, 0.4, 1.3, 1.6, 5.0]

node1 = {"startp": 0, "endp": 0.2, "item_count": 2}
node2 = {"startp": 0.4, "endp": 1.3, "item_count": 2}
node3 = {"startp": 1.6, "endp": 5.0, "item_count": 2}
```

Comment: What if there are more than 5000 items with the same price?

Comment: Do you have an API function to get all items within a certain price range, or can you only count them?

Comment: I do have a function to get all items within a certain price range. It is very unlikely to come across more than 5000 items with the same price because i'm already breaking down the items by category and if need be color.

Comment: Can we assume the minimum price is 0?

Comment: Yes we can assume that the minimum price is 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Python solution uses only functions `get_prange_count()`, and `get_max_price()` as you stated to find ranges of prices of 5k elements each. Well, I also need the minimum delta price between two prices that are not the same - I assume it is one, but .001 could be used for cents.

Item counts deviate from the 5000 due to multiple items with the same price around the bin boundaries, and the last bin which is what's left as I don't necessarily generate total prices that are a multiple of 5K.

```
import random

price_list_size = random.choice(range(90_000, 100_000))
price_list = random.choices(range(100_000), k=price_list_size)

delta_price = 1     # Minimum difference between any two different prices.

def get_prange_count(startp, endp):
    return len([r for r in price_list if startp <= r <= endp])

def get_max_price():
    return max(price_list)

def get_5k(mn=0, mx=get_max_price(), num=5_000):
    count = get_prange_count(mn, mx)
    delta_mx = (mx - mn) / 2
    while count != num and delta_mx >= delta_price / 2:
        mx += -delta_mx if count > num else +delta_mx
        count, delta_mx = get_prange_count(mn, mx), delta_mx / 2
    return mx, count

def get_all_5k(mn=0, mx=get_max_price(), num=5_000):
    partmax, partcount = get_5k(mn, mx, num)
    result = [(mn, partmax, partcount)]
    while partmax < mx:
        partmin = partmax + delta_price
        partmax, partcount = get_5k(partmin, mx, num)
        result.append((partmin, partmax, partcount))
    return result

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(f"Using {price_list_size} random prices from 0 to {get_max_price()}")
    result = get_all_5k()
    print(f"Splits into {len(result)} bins of approx 5000 elements")
    for mn, mx, count in result:
        print(f"  From {mn:8.1f} ... {mx:8.1f} with {count} items.")
```

**Sample output:**

```
Using 96625 random prices from 0 to 99997
Splits into 20 bins of approx 5000 elements
  From      0.0 ...   5144.3 with 4998 items.
  From   5145.3 ...  10266.7 with 5001 items.
  From  10267.7 ...  15504.7 with 5000 items.
  From  15505.7 ...  20584.7 with 4999 items.
  From  20585.7 ...  25701.0 with 4997 items.
  From  25702.0 ...  30907.7 with 5000 items.
  From  30908.7 ...  36111.7 with 4999 items.
  From  36112.7 ...  41304.5 with 5000 items.
  From  41305.5 ...  46588.4 with 5000 items.
  From  46589.4 ...  51771.6 with 4999 items.
  From  51772.6 ...  56861.7 with 5000 items.
  From  56862.7 ...  62156.4 with 5001 items.
  From  62157.4 ...  67289.8 with 4999 items.
  From  67290.8 ...  72393.2 with 5000 items.
  From  72394.2 ...  77545.3 with 5000 items.
  From  77546.3 ...  82747.2 with 5003 items.
  From  82748.2 ...  87995.3 with 5000 items.
  From  87996.3 ...  93270.8 with 4999 items.
  From  93271.8 ...  98331.3 with 5001 items.
  From  98332.3 ... 101660.9 with 1599 items.
```

If your true get_prange_count() function calls a slow DB then this does many calls to binary search for each bin maximum price value.

**STOP PRESS!**

I re-read your question and it says 5k ***at most***. If you make the following change to `get_5k` it will binary search as before, but if it is over 5k and `delta_mx` would be small enough to exit the outer while loop, the new inner while loop diminishes `mx` until `count` <= 5k.

```
def get_5k(mn=0, mx=get_max_price(), num=5_000):
    count = get_prange_count(mn, mx)
    delta_mx = (mx - mn) / 2
    while count != num and delta_mx >= delta_price / 2:
        mx += -delta_mx if count > num else +delta_mx
        count, delta_mx = get_prange_count(mn, mx), delta_mx / 2
        # Assure count < num
        while count > num and delta_mx < delta_price / 2 and mx > mn:
            mx -= delta_price
            count = get_prange_count(mn, mx)
    return mx, count
```

**Sample output:**

```
Using 95007 random prices from 0 to 99999
Splits into 19 bins of approx 5000 elements
  From      0.0 ...   5236.8 with 5000 items.
  From   5237.8 ...  10564.6 with 5000 items.
  From  10565.6 ...  15872.4 with 4998 items.
  From  15873.4 ...  21146.7 with 5000 items.
  From  21147.7 ...  26417.0 with 4999 items.
  From  26418.0 ...  31730.9 with 5000 items.
  From  31731.9 ...  36962.1 with 5000 items.
  From  36963.1 ...  42165.8 with 4998 items.
  From  42166.8 ...  47382.0 with 5000 items.
  From  47383.0 ...  52662.6 with 5000 items.
  From  52663.6 ...  57884.3 with 5000 items.
  From  57885.3 ...  63183.5 with 5000 items.
  From  63184.5 ...  68374.5 with 4999 items.
  From  68375.5 ...  73688.2 with 5000 items.
  From  73689.2 ...  78915.4 with 4998 items.
  From  78916.4 ...  84297.7 with 5000 items.
  From  84298.7 ...  89515.5 with 4999 items.
  From  89516.5 ...  94709.1 with 5000 items.
  From  94710.1 ... 105287.2 with 4991 items.
```

**STOP PRESS #2!!**

Further testing shows previous code drops items. The following drops no items and stays below 5k

```
def get_5k(mn=0, mx=get_max_price(), num=5_000):
    "Mainly binary search for num items between mn and mx, adjusting mx"
    count = get_prange_count(mn, mx)
    delta_mx = (mx - mn) / 2
    while count != num and delta_mx >= delta_price / 2:
        mx += -delta_mx if count > num else +delta_mx
        mx = mx // 1    # Floor
        count, delta_mx = get_prange_count(mn, mx), delta_mx / 2
        # Assure count < num
        # while count > num and delta_mx < delta_price / 2 and mx > mn:
        #     mx -= delta_price
        #     count = get_prange_count(mn, mx)
    return mx, count
```

Add the following check to the end:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(price_list) != sum(count for mn, mx, count in result):
        print("\nWhoops! Some items missing:")
        p = price_list.copy()
        for mn, mx, count in result:
            items = _get_prange(mn, mx)
            assert len(items) == get_prange_count(mn, mx)
            for i in items:
                p.remove(i)
        p.sort()
        print(p)
```

**Output is now like:**

```
Using 100941 random prices from 0 to 99999
Splits into 21 bins of approx 5000 elements
  From      0.0 ...   4918.0 with 4998 items.
  From   4919.0 ...   9863.0 with 5000 items.
  From   9864.0 ...  14901.0 with 4998 items.
  From  14902.0 ...  19708.0 with 4999 items.
  From  19709.0 ...  24605.0 with 5000 items.
  From  24606.0 ...  29555.0 with 5000 items.
  From  29556.0 ...  34539.0 with 5000 items.
  From  34540.0 ...  39507.0 with 5000 items.
  From  39508.0 ...  44602.0 with 4997 items.
  From  44603.0 ...  49462.0 with 5000 items.
  From  49463.0 ...  54458.0 with 4999 items.
  From  54459.0 ...  59432.0 with 5000 items.
  From  59433.0 ...  64315.0 with 5000 items.
  From  64316.0 ...  69416.0 with 4998 items.
  From  69417.0 ...  74389.0 with 4998 items.
  From  74390.0 ...  79253.0 with 4999 items.
  From  79254.0 ...  84149.0 with 5000 items.
  From  84150.0 ...  89134.0 with 5000 items.
  From  89135.0 ...  94059.0 with 5000 items.
  From  94060.0 ...  99055.0 with 5000 items.
  From  99056.0 ... 100934.0 with 955 items.
```

Comment: Thank you, this is very elaborate.

Comment: Hey, a follow up. Looking into the function and experimenting for a while, can you explain to me why in your get_5k function you prefer count != num instead of count > num? Thanks either way

Comment: Hi Benoni, count != num as the 5k can be approached from both sides. A count could go: 15003, 7456 6143 4867 5167 4987 5001 for example, bouncing around 5K as it gets closer. (Although I haven't checked this - I thought it would  from past experiences and coded accordingly. (I leave rigourous testing to Stack Overflow question authors and just test to get what I hope is the correct result).

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, i get it now.

Answer (score 0):

Since you can find the most expensive item, do a binary search on prices between 0 and the maximum price to find the highest price `p` such that there are fewer than 5000 items with price between 0 and `p`, using `get_prange_count` as evaluation function within the binary search. The search terminates since there are only finitely many prices to search (with 2 digits precision).

For example, if `get_prange_count(0, max) = 6000`, calculate `c = get_prange_count(0, max/2)`. If `c = 4000`, say, continue with `get_prange_count(max/2, max)` to find the highest price `p` such that `get_prange_count(max/2, p) < 6000 - c = 2000`. So the chunk size varies and is a parameter to the recursive binary search.

You can then continue doing binary searches between the current price `p` and maximum price to get the next chunks.

Here is some (rough) pseudocode:

```
search(startp, endp, threshold) {
    if (currency_round(startp) == currency_round(endp)) return startp;
    mid = startp + (endp - startp) / 2;
    count = get_prange_count(startp, mid);
    if (count == threshold) return mid;
    if (count > threshold)
        return search(startp, mid, threshold);
    // else count < threshold
    return search(mid, endp, threshold - count);
}
```

The time complexity is `O(log max)` where `max` is the maximum price.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot. I think i understand it but can you perhaps demonstrate it with the edited price_list? Thanks either way.

Comment: Sorry, it's too tedious to go through all the steps manually. I added some pseudocode to make it clearer.